# Group (average) values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays with the following data:

```
Array1 = [A, A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C];    
Array2 = [4, 2, 4, 6, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8];
```

I want to create 2 new arrays from these values:

```
Array3 = [A, B, C];    
Array4 = [4, 6, 5];
```

The values in Array 4 are the averages from Array2.

How should the javascript or jquery code look like to create Array3 and Array4?

edit:

I would like to group the values like this:

```
Array1      Array2
  A           2
  A           4
------------------
  B           2
  B           6
------------------
  C           3
  C           6
  C           9

     result:

Array3      Array4
  A           3          Average from 2 and 4
  B           4          Avarage from 2 and 6
  C           6          Average from 3, 6 and 9
```

Comment: First of all, unless `A`, `B` and `C` are not variables, your code will break. Second of all, what are averages (plural)? There is only one average value on an amount of numbers.

Comment: Instead of having two arrays linked only by index why not create an object that contains multiple arrays? Could have something like `myObj.A = [4,2,4,6]` which would be much easier to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure what people are answering!  This question doesn't make sense.  You're averaging pieces of an array, and then showing 2 different results for Array4.  How about showing some of the work you've done already so we can get a better sense of what your trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
// Your initial Variables
Array1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'];    
Array2 = [4, 2, 4, 6, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8];

// a temporary variable where we store our progress
var groups = {}

$.each(Array1, function(index,item){
    if (!groups[item]){
        groups[item] = {sum:0, count:0};
    }
    groups[item].sum += Array2[index]; // sum values belonging to same key 
    groups[item].count++; // increase counter of values per key
});

// create the letter only array
var Array3 = $.map(groups,function(value,key){
    return key;
});
// create the averages array
var Array4 = $.map(groups,function(value,key){
    return value.sum / value.count;
});

// show the results
console.log(Array3, Array4);
```

Comment: "sum values belonging to same key" ... this one comment makes the original question sensible.  It would have been nice if the original question were fixed to make it clear that the first array is a set of keys.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each value of `Array1`.  This assumes that `Array2` has identical length:

```
var Array1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'];    
var Array2 = [4, 2, 4, 6, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8];

var helper = {};

Array1.forEach(function (elem, index) {
  if (typeof helper[elem] === 'undefined') {
    helper[elem] = {'count': 0, 'total': 0} 
  }
  helper[elem].count++;
  helper[elem].total += Array2[index];
});

var Array3 = [];
var Array4 = [];

for (item in helper) {
  if (helper.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    Array3.push(item);

    Array4.push(parseInt(helper[item].total / helper[item].count));
  }
}
console.log(Array3, Array4);
```

What I did was create a helper object that stores the `Array1` values as keys and the count/total as values (the average can be computed from that).

http://jsfiddle.net/V38Lt/

Comment: +1, i only show your code in here and not the fiddle and wrote almost exactly the same.. Perhaps you should post you full code here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore, you could do:

```
//create array of form [['A',4],['B',3]...] etc.
var interleaved=_.zip(Array1,Array);

//create object of form {A:[4,2,4], ...}
var grouped=_.groupBy(interleaved,function(pair){return pair[0];});

var Array3 = _.keys(grouped);
var Array4 = _.map(grouped,function(v){return array_sum(v);});
```

`array_sum` is left an exercise to the reader. :-)

I agree with another poster that it might be better to find another way to represent this data, one which is more amenable to the kind of processing you want to do.